# Spring Security - Programmatic login without a password

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to perform an automatic login when the user clicks a link in their email with Spring Security.

I have seen a lot of examples to perform a programmatic login like the following:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
try {
    Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
    repository.saveContext(SecurityContextHolder.getContext(), request, response);
    rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(request, response, auth);
 ....
```

The problem I see is that I do not have the original password so I can't create a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. Any other way to login the user if I do not have the plain text password (I have the one that is encoded)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your beans config? (`http` namespace and `AuthenticationManager` and `AuthenticationProviders` especially.)

Comment: They just answered me below. Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Be careful that you know what you are doing in terms of allowing login from a link within an email. SMTP is not a secure protocol and so it is typically bad to rely on someone having an email as a form of authentication.

You do not need to use the AuthenticationManager if you already know they are authenticated. Instead you can just set the Authentication directly as shown below:

```
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null,
    AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

If you want a complete example, you can refer to the [SignupController](https://github.com/rwinch/spring-security-samples-securemail/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/samples/mail/mvc/SignupController.java) in the [secure mail](https://github.com/rwinch/spring-security-samples-securemail) application that was the basis for Getting Started with Spring Security 3.1 [(InfoQ video of presentation)](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Spring-Security-3-1).

Comment: Awesome answer. Thank you very much. I didn't know it was risky to do this but I will analyze which is the best approach in my case :).

Comment: What would you suggest to implement authentication without passwords in Spring then? Or, is authentication without passwords not possible in Spring?

Comment: By the way, if authentication by a link sent via email is not secure, then nearly no web site is secure, since nearly all websites are using email for password reset links. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Doesn't this assign ROLE_USER, without loading the real roles from the DB?

Comment: @Bobby ROLE_USER is spring default role I believe.

Comment: I tried your code but SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin(); still prints anonymous@localhost. What might be a reason for that? I removed password field from User

Comment: Not working for me. getPrincipal is returning wrong Object.

Comment: I'd recommend using a service like ownid.com; check out their demo https://demo.ownid.com

Comment: This worked for me, it adds right roles and sets right user:
`UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername("ivo")
Authentication authentication = new
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.authorities)
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication)`